# I am trying to export MySql data to a file using Java, but I am not able to get the table headers

Tags: java, mysql, export

I am able to export mysql to csv file but i am not getting table headers, I want headers to be displayed when my file gets saved to my system.

This is the java code which I am using:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ExportData {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String Driver;
        Statement stmt;
        Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(Driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                  "jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp", "root", "");
            if (!con.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL DataBase \n");
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                String filename = "C:/2.txt";
                String tablename = "employees";
                String sql;
                stmt.executeUpdate("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \""
                        + filename + "\" FROM " + tablename);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that was attached as a comment to the relevant MySQL manual page:

```
select 'idPago','fecha','lead','idAlumno','idTipoPago','idGpo',
    'idTaller','idDocente','pagoImporte','NoFactura','facturaImporte',
    'mes','formaPago','observaciones' union all
(select id_control_pagos, fecha, lead, id_alumno, id_concepto_pago, id_Gpo,id_Taller,
    id_docente, Pagoimporte, NoFactura, FacturaImporte, Mensualidad_No, FormaPago,
    Observaciones from control_pagos
    into outfile 'c:\\data.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```

In short, you have to add the column labels by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Comment: I used ResultSetMetaData but I am getting one exception-      Exception: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. Plz help me if you can...

Comment: ResultSetMetaData is for result of SELECT query. For UPDATE query, you will get number of rows affected.

Answer (score -3):

you cannot use `executeUpdate()` for select queries.....
use `executeQuery()`

Comment: Stop rolling back your answer. There's not much to go on anyway. You're better off deleting this yourself.